# comparison function causing problem in vector of vector sorting[leetcode]

Tags: c++, runtime-error, comparator

I needed to sort a vector of vectors by first element of each element vector. Its for the [merge intervals](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/) problem in Leetcode.
I wrote the following code for the problem:

```
class Solution {
public:
    static bool comparison(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2){
        if(v1[0]==v2[0])
            return v1[1]<=v2[1];
        else
            return v1[0]<v2[0];
    }
    
    
    vector<vector<int>> merge(vector<vector<int>>& intervals) {
        sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), comparison);
        int n = intervals.size();
        
        vector<vector<int>> res;
        if(n >= 1)
            res.push_back(intervals[0]);
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            vector<int> rv = res.back();
            vector<int> iv = intervals[i];
            if(rv[1] >= iv[0]){
                res.pop_back();
                res.push_back({min(rv[0], iv[0]), max(iv[1], rv[1])});
            }
            else{
                res.push_back(iv);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

What i tried to do in the comparison function is that, if the first element is same for the vector elements, i am sorting using the second element. This code is giving a runtime error *(runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'const int' (stl_vector.h))* for one test case only.
If I change the comparison function to the following, it is working for all testcases:

```
static bool comparison(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2){
        return v1[0]<v2[0];
}
```

Can anyone please explain the reason?

Comment: Do the vectors passed to the comparison function *have* more than a single element? Are you sure that none of the vectors passed to the comparison function actually have any elements at all?

Comment: If you read [the requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) for the comparison you will find that the relation must be a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings).

Comment: Note that `std::vector::operator<` exists, and will order 2 element vectors the same as `comparison`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude all the vector has elements and 2 elements only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparator needs to satisfy the named requirement [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) which requires a strict weak ordering. One condition you must satisfy is that:

> For all a, `comp(a,a) == false`

But for example

```
comparison({0, 0}, {0, 0});
```

yields `true`. Since your comparator does not satisfy all of the requirements you get undefined behaviour, which manifests as a crash in your case.

To restore strict weak ordering, replace `<=` with `<`:

```
static bool comparison(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2){
    if(v1[0]==v2[0])
        return v1[1] < v2[1];
    else
        return v1[0] < v2[0];
}
```

You should also check the length of the vectors first or you risk out-of-bounds access.

Comment: Thanks churill. Just curious, what should i do if need a comparator that returns true on comparing {a,a}?

Comment: Of course you can use such a comparator for your own algorithms or when you only compare two elements. But not for `std::sort`, the algorithm relies on some conditions to work properly. In the end that's due to mathematical definitions of how ordering should work and can not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we'd need to compare in the `std::sort` because it'd already sort based on the start of intervals. If you'd remove that your algorithm would work just fine:

```
struct Solution {
    vector<vector<int>> merge(vector<vector<int>>& intervals) {
        sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end());
        int n = intervals.size();

        vector<vector<int>> res;

        if (n >= 1) {
            res.push_back(intervals[0]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            vector<int> rv = res.back();
            vector<int> iv = intervals[i];

            if (rv[1] >= iv[0]) {
                res.pop_back();
                res.push_back({min(rv[0], iv[0]), max(iv[1], rv[1])});

            } else {
                res.push_back(iv);
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
};
```

A bit more conventional:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>

struct Solution {
    static std::vector<std::vector<int>> merge( std::vector<std::vector<int>> &intervals) {
        if (intervals.size() < 2) {
            return intervals;
        }

        std::sort(std::begin(intervals), std::end(intervals));

        std::vector<std::vector<int>> merged_intervals;
        merged_intervals.push_back(intervals[0]);

        for (std::size_t index = 1; index < intervals.size(); index++) {
            if (merged_intervals.back()[1] >= intervals[index][0]) {
                merged_intervals.back()[1] = std::max(merged_intervals.back()[1], intervals[index][1]);

            } else {
                merged_intervals.push_back(intervals[index]);
            }
        }

        return merged_intervals;
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector::operator[]` does not perform bound-checking. As you don't check the sizes of your vector your `comparison()` results in undefined behaviour when you put in empty vectors.

By changing the behaviour of your `comparison()` you also likely change the behaviour of your sort which can result in either empty vectors being passed in or no empty vectors being passed in. Your operator is broken nevertheless.